# Recursive method that takes an Item from the list as a parameter and checks the remaining items after it?

Tags: java

I'm new to programming and I'm asked to write code for an instance method in a LinkedList class called  isInIncreasingOrder() which returns a boolean indicating whether or not the data in the list is in increasing order.

Some requirements:

i. The method must be recursive. It makes sense to have a directly recursive 
method that takes an Item from the list as a parameter and checks the 
remaining items after it.

ii. You will need to check to make sure that there is at least one Item in the list 
before calling the recursive method.

I'm struggling to figure out how to make a recursive function that does the above. I tried following the teacher's example of his recursive function in class (which is what lead to the code below) but it doesn't really fit in with the guidelines of the method. I don't really know what to do with the parameter 'Item it'.

I'm pretty confident that I can do the 2nd requirement, but I'm struggling to meet the 1st. Any help or push in the right direction would be appreciated. Truthfully, recursion in general kind of confuses me.

```
    public boolean isInIncreasingOrder(Item it) {
        boolean sorted = true;
        for(int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
          if(list.get(i-1).compareTo(list.get(i)) > 0){
            sorted = false;
          }
        }
        return sorted;

    }
```

Here's the code for the whole class:

https://pastebin.com/MJR8TUTG

Comment: Every recursive method needs a base case. What will be the base case(s) for this method?

Comment: Your method is simply not recursive - it doesn't call itself. You are simply doing a plain check of each element. But actually doing a `list.get(num)` on a linked list is a bad idea. Also, I believe you are supposed to use this within a `LinkedList` class of your own. You should show the rest of the class.

Comment: `return it.next == null || (it.val <= it.next.val && isInIncreasingOrder(it.next));`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, think of it this way.

The list is in increasing order if:

the current list item (in your example: it) does NOT have a next item that's out of order

AND

That item also fits the same criteria (and thus your recursion).

Therefore, assuming Item has a nextItem in it...

```
public boolean isInIncreatingOrder(Item it) {
   if (it == NULL) {
       return true; // No items is always sorted
   }
   if (it.nextItem == NULL) {
       return true; // nothing after this item means it's sorted
   }
   return it.compareTo(it.nextItem) < 0 && isInIncreasingOrder(it.nextItem);
}
```

The first if checks for a NULL list. The second if is for the last item -- which by definition can't be followed by something out of item.

The return statement is the magic. It first makes sure of the relative order of this item compared to the next one. If that fails, you're out of order and the return returns false.

If it succeeds, then the list is still in order if the rest of the list is in order.

Recursion.

This is really important, @GilmoreGirling. You really really REALLY need to understand this. It's simple, but it can be hard to wrap your head around it at first.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, your function iterates through your list, which isn't recursive at all.

The thing about a linked list is that you have each item pointing to the next. I don't know about your particular implementation, but I would assume the next item can be retrieved with `it.next`, as is standard.

The concept of recursion in this case is about how you can make use of your  isInIncreasingOrder function to return if all items after the one passed as parameter are in increasing order. You only have access to that single item, not the whole list (maybe you want to see if everything after a certain element is in order, and not if the whole list is). So, you ask yourself : "How can I make use of this single function, which only takes a single item as parameter, to verify all subsequent items?". The answer is quite simple when you think about it : You check if the next item is in increasing order with yours, and if so, you ask this item to do the same.

SO you'd have something like :

```
public boolean isInIncreasingOrder(Item it) {
    if (it.value < it.next.value) {
        return isInIncreasingOrder(it.next) // It is increasing, so pass it to the next item
    }
    else {
        return null
    }
}
```

Of course, you will have to add a condition checking for when it.next points to nothing (end of your list).

Hope this helps